# Подсчитать количество повторений совпадений паттерна в строке С#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет! Друзья, возникла проблема- не могу понять почему не подсчитываются совпадения в строке. В чем может быть проблема?

Задание: Подсчитать, сколько смайликов в одной строке. Смайлики могут с такими глазами:":;"  с носом:"-" и ртами:")]([" (рты могут повторяться)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            string line = null;
            string pattern = @"^([:|;]{1}[-]*[)|(|[|\]]+)$";
            Regex reg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            Console.WriteLine("Введите строку на проверку корректности:");
            line = Console.ReadLine();

            MatchCollection mc = reg.Matches(line);


            foreach (Match mat in mc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mat.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine(mc.Count.ToString());

        }//for
    }//main
```

Comment: Уберите знаки начала и конца строки -  "([:|;]{1}[-]*[)|(|[|\]]+)" так должно работать. Потестить можно тут https://regex101.com/r/Be3kmn/1

Comment: Спасибо, приятель!

Answer (score 1):

> Смайлики могут с такими глазами:":;" с носом:"-" и ртами:")]([" (рты могут повторяться)

В таком случае, `[:|;]` содержит лишний `|`, в символьных классах `|` не является оператором ИЛИ, а просто означает данный символ. В `[)|(|[|\]]` та же проблема, хотя, если необходимо найти `:-|`, то `|` лучше оставить в единственном экземпляре. Кстати, если `]` поставить в символьном классе сразу после открывающего его символа `[`, то `]` не нуждается в экранировании. `{1}` лучше удалять из регулярок, написанных вручную, так как без квантификатора любой шаблон находит ровно одно совпадение. `[-]` не нужно экранировать или заключать в символьный класс, так как вне символьного класса `-` не является специальным метасимволом.

Кроме вышеперечисленного, символы `^` / `$` являются "якорями", они привязывают шаблон к началу и концу строки. Поэтому, ваша регулярка найдёт строку типа `:-)`, но не найдёт строку типа `Нет :(`. Удалите их из выражения.

Используйте

```
"[:;]-*[][()]+"
```

[См. демо](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%3A%3B%5D-*%5B%5D%5B%28%29%5D%2B&i=%3A%29%20%3A%29%20%3A%C3%A0%20%3B%29%20kkk) (тестируйте регулярные выражения для .NET на сайтах, которые поддерживают его синтаксис, регес101 не поддерживает .NET).

Параметр `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` здесь не нужен, в регулярке нет букв.

Код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        string line = null;
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"[:;]-*[][()]+");
        Console.WriteLine("Введите строку на проверку корректности:");
        line = Console.ReadLine();
        MatchCollection mc = reg.Matches(line);
        foreach (Match mat in mc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mat.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(mc.Count.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не хотите иметь дело с Regex, можно проще реализовать. S-массив смайликов.

```
private Int32 CountWords(string[] S, String S0)
{
    string[] temp = S0.Split(S, StringSplitOptions.None);
    return temp.Length - 1;
}
```